# Java GC kicks in around 2.5GB despite -Xmx10G

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a question about Java Garbage Collection on big heap sizes.

When I execute my Java program on 64-bit windows with 64-bit JDK (`java8u72`) with:

```
java -Xmx10G -Xms6G -verbose:gc <Class>
```

Then:

- `java.exe` memory utilization stays around 2.5 GB (Windows Task Manager).
- I get GC every 10-30 seconds with around the same values: `[GC (Allocation Failure)  2766094K->239630K(6647808K), 0.0270937 secs]`

First, **what does this mean?** This 2766094K is before heap utilization (2.7G), then 239630 (2.3G) is after, and then 6647808K (6G) is the heap size, right?

**Why does the GC kicks in around 2.5G when I asked for a  max heap of 10 GB?**  How to fix this?

My laptop has 8 GB physical RAM, but I assume that a bigger heap size is handled by virtual memory and transparant for the VM!?

Tx

Comment: if it really gets 10g then it is the young generation being GCed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 6647808K (6G) is the heap size in young generation. It is not the actual heap size.
2. As heap size is divided in young and old generation, typically the ratio is 1:8 between young gen and old gen. So, rest 4 GB is allocated to Old gen. 
   JVM has failed to allocate memory in young gen and hence it gas initiated minor GC, so the object size in young gen is 2766094K and after minor GC memory size has become 239630K.

Check when Full GC is perfomed. It would be like below -

[Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 11605K->0K(150016K)] [ParOldGen: 27075K->32787K(87040K)] 38681K->32787K(237056K), [Metaspace: 19481K->19481K(1067008K)], 0.0989447 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs]

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause may be that you're trying to allocate a big block of memory (e.g. a large array, possibly through an `ArrayList`). Having enough free space *in total* is not sufficient to allocate memory for a large array, the free space also needs to be uninterrupted (you need a block of memory that's all free and at least as big as your array).

E.g., if you try to create an array of size 5 and you have free memory in blocks of 3, 3, and 2, Java still needs to do GC even though you have 8 units of free memory in total.